# How to plot spheres with Julia?

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Simple Problem, I have a data set with x-,y-,z-coordinates and the volume of each sphere.
Should be enough data to plot these spheres? Isn't it?

I'm new to Julia and I actually have no clue how to do this.
Couldn't find any similar and helpful answer...

Thank you,
Tom

[image: Should look like that]

Comment: As an alternative, there are a couple of examples using Gaston.jl here: https://mbaz.github.io/Gaston.jl/stable/3d-gallery/#Spheres-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [Makie](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Makie.jl) would be a good option. The documentation for [meshscatter](http://makie.juliaplots.org/dev/plotting_functions.html#meshscatter) gives an example that can be adapted to better fit what you'd like to achieve:

```julia
using Makie

x = 100*rand(10)
y = 100*rand(10)
z = 100*rand(10)
scene = meshscatter(x, y, z, markersize = 10, color = :white)
Makie.save("plot.png", scene)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great! Do you know why the plot isn't working in **nteract**? I tried your example but I get no plot result, everything else works fine. Also no error.

Comment: **Print:** Scene (1920px, 1080px):
  2 Plots:
    ├ Axis3D{...}
    └ MeshScatter{...}
  0 Child Scenes

Comment: Might be because nteract does not know how to display the resulting scene. A workaround to that would be to save the generated scene as an image, and display the image instead.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is PyPlot:

```
using PyPlot

N = 32
u = range(0, stop=2π, length=N)
v = range(0, stop=π, length=N)
x = cos.(u) .* sin.(v)'
y = sin.(u) .* sin.(v)'
z = repeat(cos.(v)',outer=[N, 1])
PyPlot.surf(x,y,z)
PyPlot.savefig("plot.png")
```

[image]

Comment: This looks more like an oblate spheroid. There's a way to fix this with some setaspectratio command or something, but I don't have time to find it right now.